# SocketAsyncEventArgs, Max Connections and what happens when these are in use

Tags: c#, sockets, tcp, asyncsocket

This may sound like a stupid question but I have repeatedly searched for the answers to no avail.

What I want to know is what would be a sensible size for the SocketAsyncEventArgs read/write pool, what should the backlog size be set to on the listening socket and are the two directly linked. Also are these values directly linked to the performance of the socket server and what could be the effects of change one or the other, or both.

Also what happens if the listening socket backlog is full, will this prohibit clients from connecting? (I'm currently assuming it will) And if all the readwrite SocketAsyncEventArgs from the pool are currently in use will the listening socket wait until one becomes free?

At the minute both are using the same value of 10.

If this depends on the type of machine this is running on it will be a single core windows 2012 server with 2gb of ram to begin with and will be expanding to 6 core with 20gb once put to work properly.

Below will show the initialization of my socket listener

```
/// <summary>
    /// The socket used to listen for incoming connection requests.
    /// </summary>
    private Socket listenSocket;

    /// <summary>
    /// Mutex to synchronize server execution.
    /// </summary>
    private static Mutex mutex = new Mutex();

    /// <summary>
    /// Buffer size to use for each socket I/O operation.
    /// </summary>
    private Int32 bufferSize;

    /// <summary>
    /// The total number of clients connected to the server.
    /// </summary>
    private Int32 numConnectedSockets;

    /// <summary>
    /// the maximum number of connections the sample is designed to handle simultaneously.
    /// </summary>
    private Int32 numConnections;

    /// <summary>
    /// Pool of reusable SocketAsyncEventArgs objects for write, read and accept socket operations.
    /// </summary>
    private SocketAsyncEventArgsPool readWritePool;

    /// <summary>
    /// Controls the total number of clients connected to the server.
    /// </summary>
    private Semaphore semaphoreAcceptedClients;

    /// <summary>
    /// Create an uninitialized server instance.  
    /// To start the server listening for connection requests
    /// call the Init method followed by Start method.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="numConnections">Maximum number of connections to be handled simultaneously.</param>
    /// <param name="bufferSize">Buffer size to use for each socket I/O operation.</param>
    internal SocketListener(Int32 numConnections, Int32 bufferSize)
    {
        this.numConnectedSockets = 0;
        this.numConnections = numConnections;
        this.bufferSize = bufferSize;

        this.readWritePool = new SocketAsyncEventArgsPool(numConnections);
        this.semaphoreAcceptedClients = new Semaphore(numConnections, numConnections);

        // Preallocate pool of SocketAsyncEventArgs objects.
        for (Int32 i = 0; i < this.numConnections; i++)
        {
            SocketAsyncEventArgs readWriteEventArg = new SocketAsyncEventArgs();
            readWriteEventArg.Completed += new EventHandler<SocketAsyncEventArgs>(OnIOCompleted);
            readWriteEventArg.SetBuffer(new Byte[this.bufferSize], 0, this.bufferSize);

            // Add SocketAsyncEventArg to the pool.
            this.readWritePool.Push(readWriteEventArg);
        }
    }
```

And this shows what happens when the start method is called of the socket listener is called.

```
internal void Start(Int32 port)
    {
        // Get host related information.
        IPAddress[] addressList = Dns.GetHostEntry(Environment.MachineName).AddressList;

        // Get endpoint for the listener.
        IPEndPoint localEndPoint = new IPEndPoint(addressList[addressList.Length - 1], port);

        // Create the socket which listens for incoming connections.
        this.listenSocket = new Socket(localEndPoint.AddressFamily, SocketType.Stream, ProtocolType.Tcp);
        this.listenSocket.ReceiveBufferSize = this.bufferSize;
        this.listenSocket.SendBufferSize = this.bufferSize;

        if (localEndPoint.AddressFamily == AddressFamily.InterNetworkV6)
        {
            // Set dual-mode (IPv4 & IPv6) for the socket listener.
            // 27 is equivalent to IPV6_V6ONLY socket option in the winsock snippet below,
            // based on http://blogs.msdn.com/wndp/archive/2006/10/24/creating-ip-agnostic-applications-part-2-dual-mode-sockets.aspx
            this.listenSocket.SetSocketOption(SocketOptionLevel.IPv6, (SocketOptionName)27, false);
            this.listenSocket.Bind(new IPEndPoint(IPAddress.IPv6Any, localEndPoint.Port));
        }
        else
        {
            // Associate the socket with the local endpoint.
            this.listenSocket.Bind(localEndPoint);
        }

        // Start the server.
        this.listenSocket.Listen(this.numConnections);

        // Post accepts on the listening socket.
        this.StartAccept(null);

        // Blocks the current thread to receive incoming messages.
        mutex.WaitOne();
    }
```

Sorry if this is a long winded question its just I really dont know where else to look. Any help will be greatly appreciated

This code has been taken from a really good article on Codeproject in which the author based his code on the MSDN example. It can be found here

http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/22918/How-To-Use-the-SocketAsyncEventArgs-Class